# Complex regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

A complex regex to me atleast.   This is a string I have:

```
/wp-content/themes/modern2/timthumb.php?src=http://www.cnn.com/storyimages/4C59D569-7749-F32B.jpg&h=442&w=642&zc=1&s=2
```

what I want to do is change the url contained in that string to another url of my choosing ie.

```
http://www.cnn.com/storyimages/4C59D569-7749-F32B.jpg
```

TO

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Google-Logo.svg
```

I cant figure out how to regex match/replace the data between src= and &h=

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must it be done with regex?

```
function replaceURL(sourceURL, newPart) {
    var beforeSrc = sourceURL.split('?src=')[0];
    var afterH = sourceURL.split('&h=')[1];

    return beforeSrc + '?src=' + newPart + '&h=' + afterH;
}
```

Then just call

```
replaceURL(
    '/wp-content/themes/modern2/timthumb.php?src=http://www.cnn.com/storyimages/4C59D569-7749-F32B.jpg&h=442&w=642&zc=1&s=2',
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Google-Logo.svg'
);
```

Note that this is valid because in valid URL, the `?src` substring cannot appear any sooner than at the place you expect it, nor can `&h` appear any later.

Comment: Eh, forgot to add the delimiters back, wrong case on src... edited, now it should be ok. One can't simply write code sleepy and without testing first :(

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not necessary to use regex, but since you asked...

```
var str = '/wp-content/themes/modern2/timthumb.php?src=http://www.cnn.com/storyimages/4C59D569-7749-F32B.jpg&h=442&w=642&zc=1&s=2'
var url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Google-Logo.svg'
str = str.replace(/src=(.*?)&/, 'src=' + url +'&')
```

Output:

```
/wp-content/themes/modern2/timthumb.php?src=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Google-Logo.svg&h=442&w=642&zc=1&s=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use regular expresion like this:

```
src=([^&$]+)
```

Here are [regexp](http://regexr.com?30u4a) and [code](http://jsfiddle.net/6eryk/) examples.